# ECLIPSE_HOME not defined?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I just installed (copy and pasted the files) eclipse IDE for c/c++ but I keep getting this error from various plugins that says 
ECLIPSE_HOME is undefined. But I am still able to use cmake to build my project.

I've added the environmental variable ECLIPSE_HOME to c:\program files\eclipse but It did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In c:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\config.ini try to put this line:

```
eclipse.home=c:\Program Files\eclipse\
```